# How to get last year's date in Unix Bourne Shell?

Tags: date, sh

I know of methods to get the date from yesterday, 1 month ago, etc.

How do you get the date from 1 year ago?

For example:

Current date `20120802` and last year's date `20110802`.

Of course I could change the `2012` to `2011`, but is there a way that does not require manual intervention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use:

```
date --date="1 year ago"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you also know how to get the date 1 year ago from a certain date? For example the date 1 year ago from `20120801` would be `20110801`.

Comment: date --date="2012-08-01 1 year ago"

Comment: Thank you so much...the syntax is so beautimazing

Comment: You can also format, i.e. ```date +%m%d%y --date='last year'```

Answer (score 0):

for more..

You can see here..

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html